# Unit Test Coverage is not coming in Sonarqube

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have configured Jenkins 2.31.1 with Maven 3.3.9 , and I am using Sonarqube 5.6.4, when I am building my Java project from Jenkins then test cases are getting executed also I am getting report in Sonarqube but Unit Tests Coverage is coming as "**-**".

Can anyone explain the steps to resolve this issue? How can I get Unit Tests Coverage? What are the changes I need to do ? What are the steps to be followed? Am I missing something here?

Here is link to my git repository - 
https://github.com/swapnil0504/HelloFromMaven.git

Comment: How are you calling sonarqube analysis? Which version of sonarqube plugin do you use?

Comment: I'm calling it from Jenkins.

Comment: This answer does not help...I asked how are you calling sonarqube analysis? BTW: Have you tested it from command line...

Comment: After installing Jenkins we can add Sonarqube Plugin and Sonar Scanner in Jenkins and then we can add per project, while adding we can configure that after build trigger Sonar.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

In my case Sonarqube is getting trigger BUILD is successful also I got analysis report but only unit test coverage has not displayed.

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried from command line too but again Unit Test Coverage is -.
In order to do it from command line I have modified settings.xml of maven, added profile and pluginGroup and then in work space I executed 
mvn clean
mvn install
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:3306/sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar/

Still Unit Test Coverage is not appearing ....

Comment: If you are working with a recent version of Sonar the things in settings.xml are not needed in particular jdbc etc. Configure the sonar-maven-plugin correctly based on the documentation at SonarQube wiki. Furthermore have you bound jacoco-maven-plugin to your build to get coverage ?

Comment: Is it required ? Because I'm using only JUnit